# SQL Server: ISNULL on uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, uniqueidentifier, isnull

I am trying to compare a column `col1` and a variable `@myvar` in a `WHERE` clause. Both usually contain GUIDs, but may also have NULL values. 
I thought I could get around the fact that `NULL=NULL` evaluates to FALSE by using `WHERE ISNULL(col1, '')=ISNULL(@myvar, '')`. That would compare two empty strings instead, and evaluate to TRUE.

This will, however, produce the following error message:

> Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 3 Conversion failed when converting
>   from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

I tried

```
DECLARE @myvar uniqueidentifier = NULL
SELECT ISNULL(@myvar,'') as col1
```

Same error message.

Two questions:
First, I am trying to convert a uniqueidentifier variable - even though it has a NULL value - to an (empty!) string, not the other way around, as the error message suggests. What gives?

Second, is there a better way to word that WHERE clause I need, to allow for comparing uniqueidentifiers that might be NULL?

Comment: Do you want your valid uniqueidentifiers to be converted to strings too?

Comment: shawnt00, for the WHERE clause the non-NULL uniqueidentifiers don't need to be converted to strings. Comparing them just has to evaluate to TRUE so I only retrieve records where they are equal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the first argument you are passing `isnull` is not a **literal `null`**, it will determine the return type of that call, a `uniqueidentifier` in your case. The second argument, `''`, cannot be cast to this type, hence the error you're getting.

One way around this is just to explicitly check for `null`s:

```
WHERE (@myvar IS NULL AND col1 IS NULL) OR (col1 = @myvar)
```

Comment: There is a second part important to keep in mind. At the moment you put a column into a function (like ISNULL) you make it impossible for the query optimizer to use its potential. Look at this ("sargable"): http://stackoverflow.com/q/799584/5089204

Comment: Shnugo, I had not even considered this. This might come to make an important difference, as all this is going to be part of a python program that is going to run this query (or very similar ones) thousands of times in a row (through pyodbc), so any time savings be they ever so small may count!

Comment: @Shnugo, having looked into this further, am I right to assume that this applies to user defined functions as well as built-in functions...?

Comment: @ThorstenVogt, yes, the biggest deal with performance is to let the optimizer do its work. Non-sargable parts can make queries awfully slow, but you cannot imagine why ...

Answer (score 17):

I think below expression can be used to check if the GUID column is empty

```
CAST(0x0 AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

some thing like

```
...WHERE GuidId <>  CAST(0x0 AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to overcome this issue:

```
DECLARE @myvar uniqueidentifier = NEWID()

SELECT * FROM TABLE
Where ISNULL(col1,@myvar) = ISNULL(Col2,@myvar)
```

This will resolve your error. Conversion failed when converting from a character string to `uniqueidentifier`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason `ISNULL` isn't working for you is that the replacement value (the value to be used if the check expression really is null) must be implicitly convertible to the type of the check expression.

Your `WHERE` clause can use a `col IS NULL AND @var IS NULL` to check that state.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, exclude the NULL values from the results and THEN do the comparison. You can use COALESCE to exclude NULL values from comparisons.

Comment: Look at my comment below @Mureinik. Avoid function calls (COALESCE) for "sargability"

Comment: What would have been better is a sample showing how to convert a non-sargable where clause into a sargable select statement, both using COALESCE or ISNULL to solve the problem.

Comment: COALESCE would solve the problem with the error I get nicely. I will take the added potential performance bonus, though.    :o)  I only need this for the WHERE clause though, not the SELECT statement.

Comment: @EmacsUser, if you follow the link I postet in my comment below Mureinik's answer you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: @TVogt, Maybe I do not understand you correctly, but it is wrong to hope, that something in the WHERE would not influence the query itself. It is exactly the other way round! Just imagine your "WHERE" filters a table with millions of rows down to just a few. This should probably be the first step. If the optimizer cannot look "into" it, this filter is applied **after** the select. Millions of rows are fetched - and thrown away at the end...

Comment: @Shnugo, no, you explained this quite well. First, the WHERE clause limits which records to fetch - thereby determining the rows; then the SELECT statement tells the database what data to get out of those rows, by choosing the columns. And as I understand it, performance gains are achieved predominantly by limiting the number of rows, more so than the number of columns. Yes?

Comment: @TVogt, well, there's not enough space to explain the query optimizer in detail. But in short: Yes, few rows mean little work. The optimizer is much more intelligent actually (read about joins, indexes, statistic, scan vs. seek). There are very few situations, where a developer should influence this (read about hints). Normally it's best not to stand in the way :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
WHERE ISNULL([Guid], NEWID()) = @myvar
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This still has the problem of treating two nulls as not equal to each other, since NEWID() returns a random GUID, not a blank GUID.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar on a where clause to compare 2 fields.
Declaring a uniqueidentifier variable is causing performance issues.

So I've used something like this.

```
WHERE COALESCE(Table1.Field1, CAST('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER))=COALESCE(Table2.Field2, CAST('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER))
```